# Can anyone help me to turn this string into an array of numbers without losing zeros(0).And not using regExp

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me to turn this string into an array of numbers without losing zeros(0)? And not using regExp

`"00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80" -> [0,0,67,4,0,0,0,700,80]`

```
function extractNumbers(string) {
    let arrNumbs = [];
    let numbers = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        let elem = string.charAt(i);
        if (!isNaN(elem)) {
            numbers += elem;
        } else if (numbers !== "") {
            arrNumbs.push(parseInt(numbers));
            numbers = "";
        }
    }
    if (numbers !== "") {
        arrNumbs.push(parseInt(numbers));
        return arrNumbs;
    }
    return arrNumbs;
}
extractNumbers("00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80");
console.log(extractNumbers(string)); //->[ 0, 67, 4, 0, 700, 80 ]
```

Comment: Seems you are looking for substrings that are all zero to be separated as values in the return array, yet numbers that are not zero should stay adjoined, is this correct?

Comment: If you use `parseInt()` to get a number from a string, then the leading zeros don't matter; the number has the same value.

Comment: @dalelandry yes, that's right, for example like this "00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80" -> [0,0,67,4,0,0,0,700,80]  What my code does - missing all the 0 before the numbers, but keeps them after

Comment: If you want to keep the leading zero digits you have to keep that `numbers` value a string and not parse it. As a number, the string "0007" is *exactly* the same value as "7" is.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind not wanting to use regex for this? Regex would really simplify this though you have a few examples of how to do it without regex below.

Comment: I would also ask the following as Pointy made a good point, npi, what if your string contains `hj 97jk 0010gr70` would your expected output be => `[97,0010,70]` or `[97,0,0,10,70]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a special case for 0.

```js
function extractNumbers(string) {
    let arr = [], curr = "";
    function add() {
      if (curr) arr.push(+curr), curr = "";
    }
    for (const c of string) {
      if (!curr && c === '0') arr.push(0);
      else if (c < '0' || c > '9') add();
      else curr += c;
    }
    add();
    return arr;
}
console.log(extractNumbers("00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80"));
```

Comment: Your code breaks for some strings because of whitespace, e.g. `" "` (whitespace-only), `"a a"` (whitespace substring between non-numeric characters): [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) coerces its argument; [number coercion of whitespace-only strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion) evaluates to 0. Perhaps try parsing instead of coercion?

Answer (score 1):

But if anyone is looking for regexp instead:

```js
function extractNumbers (str) {
    return str.match(/0|[1-9]\d*/g).map(v => +v);
}
console.log(extractNumbers('00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80'));
```

Comment: did you read the question :: `And not using regExp`

Comment: @MisterJojo Of course I did. This is why I added "But if" =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `parseInt(numbers)` will skip the leading zeros. So you have to handle it in a special case. I have modified your code.

```
function extractNumbers(string) {
  let arrNumbs = [];
  let numbers = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let elem = string.charAt(i);
    // if it's zero, add it and reset numbers 
    // this will handle leading zeros
    if (numbers === "0") {
      arrNumbs.push(0);
      numbers = "";
    }
    if (!isNaN(elem)) {
      numbers += elem;
    } else if (numbers !== "") {
      arrNumbs.push(parseInt(numbers));
      numbers = "";
    }
  }
  if (numbers !== "") {
    arrNumbs.push(parseInt(numbers));
    return arrNumbs;
  }
  return arrNumbs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a shorter one:

```js
document.write(JSON.stringify(extractNumbers('00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80')));

function extractNumbers(str)
  {
  let arr = [], sNum = '';
  for (const c of str + '_')
    {
    if      (c==='0' && !sNum)  arr.push(0);
    else if (!isNaN(c))         sNum += c.trimEnd();
    else if (!!sNum)
      {
      arr.push(parseInt(sNum,10));
      sNum = '';
      }
    }
  return arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this (assuming that leading zeros should be treated as individual numbers):

1. For `text[i] === "0"`, push 0 and continue.
2. Parse starting at `i` as number; continue if `NaN`.
3. Push number.
4. Skip for amount of digits in number.

```js
const text = "00a1b c010d ";
console.log(extractNumbers(text));

function extractNumbers(text) {
  const numbers = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
    if (text[i] === "0") {
      numbers.push(0);
      continue;
    }
    
    const number = parseInt(text.substring(i));
    if (Number.isNaN(number)) continue;
    
    numbers.push(number);
    i += Math.floor(Math.log10(number));
  }
  
  return numbers;
}
```

**Note**: Instead of continuing in case of `NaN` *after parsing*, you could *generally* continue in case of `text[i]` being non-numeric (e.g. by checking `/\D/.test(text[i])`).

Answer (score -1):

Turn the input string into an array of individual characters using the spread operator. Then, in the accumulator array of `reduce`, start a new string whenever we reach a digit directly after a non-digit (and also when a string containing only zero is followed by another zero). Then, for numeric characters, append it to the most recent string in the accumulator array. Finally, use the `+` operator to coerce the the array of strings into an array of numbers.

```js
const isNum = c => c>='0' && c<='9'

console.log([...'00ghj67 h4 h000ytff700jhjk80'].reduce((a,c,i,r) => (
  (a[a.length-1]==='0' && c==='0' || isNum(c) && i && !isNum(r[i-1]))
  && a.push(''), isNum(c) && (a[a.length-1] += c), a), ['']).map(i => +i))
```